# JQuery Ajax Fileupload automatically submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, upload

I have this form

```
<form id="fileupload" name="fileupload" action="/HelloStruts2/views/audioupload.action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="" id="fileupload_title"/>
    <input type="file" name="audioUpload" value="" id="fileupload_audioUpload"/>

    <input type="submit" id="fileupload_0" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

that expects a user input and a file from the user, once the user has selected the file to be upload, once he clicks okay he automatically submits it, I want the form be submitted on submit, not after the user has chosen the file. Here's my script

```
  $('#fileupload').submit(function(e){
        $(this).fileupload({
            dataType: 'html',
            add: function (e, data) {
                data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
                    .appendTo(document.body)
                    .click(function () {
                        $(this).replaceWith($('<p/>').text('Uploading...'));
                        data.submit();
                    });
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                $('#fileupload').empty().append(data.result);
            }
        });
    });
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin. I have tried binding the an event to it but it is not submitting the form so I decided to revert back to its normal submission

Comment: It is in the documentation: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin. Read the section "How to start uploads with a button click
"

Comment: I tried it already , but to no avail it is not working. I have updated my script look at it